# Use htaccess to mask domain and folder name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use htaccess and mod_rewrite to mask one domain and two of its sub-folders with another domain. For example: `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/` to `http://example-2.com/` So that `http://example-2.com/` is what shows in the browser address bar, but the content of `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/` is what's displaying on the page.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983391/use-htaccess-to-mask-folder-name) question/answer which should accomplish this, but it doesn't work when I implement it.

Current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/%1 [L]

Options -Multiviews
```

Here's a view of my directory:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nihz1al.png]

Comment: Okay, but which strings are fixed and which dynamic in both URLs. That's the relevant information in this type of question. The rest seems clear: You want to map silently `http://example-2.com/` to `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/`, but what's the correlation between `example-2.com` and `sub/sub-sub`, for example, what in the incoming URL is supposed to be passed to the substitution URL, or nothing is passed?

Comment: In the URL `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/`, anything after the sub-sub folder should be passed to the substitution URL. For example, if I had `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/a-page.php`, then the substitution URL should show `http://example-2.com/a-page.php`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape `-`, except inside a character class. And even there, you can have it unescaped as the first or last character.

In a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), the pattern is tested against the URL-path and not the domain. If you need to test against the domain, you can use a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example-2.com
RewriteRule ^/?sub/sub-sub/(.*) http://example-2.com/$0 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example-2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?sub/sub-sub
RewriteRule .* sub/sub-sub/$0
```

Comment: This works in that when I visit `http://example-2.com/page`, it displays correctly in the browser and address bar. But I also want it to display as `http://example-2.com/page` in the address bar when I visit `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/page`. So no matter what domain I use, `http://example-2.com` always shows in the address bar, but the content of `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub` always displays on the page. Does that make sense? It's hard to explain.

Comment: @ElliPetersen I added an external redirect, for all domains *not* `example-2.com`. Please check, if this works for you.

Comment: Now when I visit `http://example-2.com/page` it redirects to `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/page` in the address bar too. So it's almost there! Now we just need to make `http://example-2.com/page` stay in the address bar. I'm sorry if this is frustrating, I don't understand htaccess very well.

Comment: @ElliPetersen I forgot another RewriteCond to prevent an endless loop.

Comment: @ElliPetersen I just looked at your current .htaccess. The difference between your and my RewriteRule is, I do an internal and you do an external rewrite. If you omit `http://example.com/`, `http://example-2.com/page` should stay  in the browser's address bar. It does so in my test environment.

Comment: +1 @OlafDietsche  I still don't understand why ends up in another domain as the question requires, but obviously you did. Good analysis.

Comment: @faa Often, this evolves with the question and especially the answers. And sometimes, you can figure it out from the comments. And again, with the answers the OP sometimes realizes, what she really needs. But I'm still barking up the wrong tree often enough. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/sub/sub-sub         [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)                 [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/%1 [L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://example-2.com/anything`

To:

`http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/anything`

All string are assumed to be fixed, except the segment path `anything`.

For permanent an visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`.

The above rule-set must be included in one .htaccess file in `http://example-2.com` root directory.

#### UPDATE:

To skip the rule for any incoming URL without a path, like `http://example-2.com/`, replace this line:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)  [NC]`

with this one:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.+)  [NC]`

Comment: This works, but seems to create an infinite loop when I visit `http://example-2.com` directly (`http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/sub/sub-sub/sub/sub-sub/sub/sub-sub/sub/sub-sub/` etc). Also, now when I visit `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/anything`, I get a 404 error. It's because I'm using another rewrite rule to remove .php from pages.

I've edited my original question with my current htaccess.

Comment: Switch the sets of rules position. The loop is not generate by the set in my answer and it does what you asked for.

Comment: I completely removed the other set of rules, and now this works, though visiting `http://example-2.com/page` redirects in the address bar to `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/page`. I tried changing `[R=301,L]` to `[L]` but that created the same redirect problem.

I've updated my current htaccess for `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/` in the main question. I probably wasn't clear enough in what I'm wanting to do. See my comment on the answer below for what I hope is a better explanation.

Comment: @Elli I don't quite understand. What do you want to do when the URL is just `http://example-2.com/`, leave it like that without redirection? If so, just replace `^/(.*)` with this `^/(.+)`

Comment: Correct, because `http://example-2.com/` already points to `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/` via server settings. I replaced that line, but it's still creating a loop. I've updated my current htaccess in the main question.

Comment: OK. I will update my answer with another condition to try to prevent loops. What you asked makes sense and I should have realized that any URL without path should not be redirected.

Comment: @Elli Updated it. If necessary, please fill in the correct folder names in the new condition in my answer: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/sub/sub-sub   [NC]`

Comment: Now visiting `http://example-2.com/` goes to `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/index.html` and creates a 404. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: Well, it goes where the server setting is redirecting it: "because `http://example-2.com/` **already points to**  `http://example.com/sub/sub-sub/` via server setting" . You should try to combine all rules into one set. The loop you had was never originated by the rules in my answer, but by those previous conflicting rules.