# Use htaccess to mask wp-admin folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Same question: [Use htaccess to mask folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983391/use-htaccess-to-mask-folder-name)

but the answer doesnt work. My `.htaccess` file curently look like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard(.*)$ wp-admin$1
```

and I always get:

> **The page isn't redirecting properly**
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

`dashboard`-`wp-admin` it seems like redirecting to each other; I just want to displaying `mysite.com/dashboard` but the content must be `mysite.com/wp-admin`, I am using wordpress 3.5.1. it is possible, isn't it? I am not good at all in server stuff; so please help;

Thanks.

Comment: Is `/dashboard/` a real directory?

Comment: @JonLin no, it is not. I only want to replace url display.

Comment: How exactly is this off topic? Not only is it revelant to WordPress, it is something I'd imagine a lot of people would want to do.

Comment: This is not off topic

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're getting the **The page isn't redirecting properly** error on your browser, but if the `/dashboard` directory doesn't physically exist, those requests will get routed through index.php (wordpress). You should try swapping the order of your rules so that the redirects happen *before* the routing:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard(.*)$ wp-admin$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This way, when you request `http://mysite.com/dashboard`, the 2nd rule will get applied instead of the `RewriteRule . /index.php` rule.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason why your page isn't redirecting properly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Try to change your entire `.htaccess` with this directives:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#Where the
#suspected
#code located
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#HERE
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/?$ /dashboard [R,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)/?$ /dashboard/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)$ /wp-admin/$1
```

If it's not working, then try to change the comment `#HERE` with `RewriteEngine on`.