# How to remove subdirectory from url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, masking

When a visitor visits my site and reads a post, they see this in the address bar:
`http://www.example.com/darkalfx/?p=71`

How can I mask the url so that it shows this in the address bar:
`http://www.example.com/?p=71`

Basically I just want any page in that sub directory to show without the `/darkalfx/` in the url.

This is what I have so far in my .htaccess
`# Externally redirect only direct client requests for /index.php and`
`# /index.html and /index.htm with /darkalfx to root URL ending with slash.`
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /darkalfx/([^/]+/)*index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/`
`RewriteRule ^darkalfx/(([^/]+/)*)index.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`# Externally redirect only direct client requests for /darkalfx<something>`
`# to www.example.com/<something>.`
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /darkalfx([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/`
`RewriteRule ^darkalfx(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`# Externally redirect only direct client requests for /index.php`
`# and /index.html and /index.htm to URL ending with slash.`
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/`
`RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index.(html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`# Externally redirect to canonicalize the domain name if a non-canonical`
`# hostname is requested, in order to prevent duplicate-content problems`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$`
`RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`# Internally rewrite requests for www.example.com/<anything>`
`# to internal server path at /darkalfx/<anything>`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/darkalfx`
`RewriteRule (.*) /darkalfx/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Link:
[Use htaccess to mask folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983391/use-htaccess-to-mask-folder-name)

Answer:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /foo/
    RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ foo/$1
```

In your case ^bar is going to be home or prob /
I have no .htacess exp

Comment: Which .htaccess file would I edit? The one in the subdirectory or the root?

Comment: The .htaccess in root.  Should try to only have one .htaccess file and  put in root