# How to remove brand or any text from Woo commerce archive page URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce page whose URL is like

https://www.example.com/brand/cocacola

I want to remove brand from URL and there will be no 404 error come

This link
https://www.example.com/brand/cocacola

Need to convert into 
https://www.example.com/cocacola

But, the content of the page will be the same on archive page

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You can do it by using `.htaccess`

Comment: Can you please guide me how?

Answer (score 2):

```
I have got a solution to this problem.

**STEP (1)**

Add the below code in functions.php file

<!-- product_brand is your taxonomy name. Can be viewable from admin -->

 add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function( $args, $taxonomy ){


  if( 'product_brand' === $taxonomy && is_array( $args ) ){
    $args['rewrite']['slug']       = '/';
    $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
  }
  return $args;
}, 99, 2 );

**STEP (2)**

Save and refresh your permalink 


** Code tested and its working fine.
```

Answer (score 1):

`$str = "http://www.example.com/brand/cocacola";
$list = explode("/", $str);
echo $list[3];

echo ' or ';

$arr = explode('/'.$list[3], $str);
echo $arr[0] . $arr[1];`

should print out:
brand or http://www.example.com/cocacola

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this is called masking with .htaccess and symlink

Here is a stackoverflow post that is relevant.

[Use htaccess to mask folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983391/use-htaccess-to-mask-folder-name)

Another option is to just use a wordpress filter

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function( $args, $taxonomy ){
  if( 'brand' === $taxonomy && is_array( $args ) ){
    $args['rewrite']['slug']       = '.';
    $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
  }
  return $args;
}, 99, 2 );
```

Then refresh your permalinks (code not tested, do enter into a live site.)

Comment: its remove the brand from url but taking on 404 page.

Comment: Its working fine after a small change in this code. I replaced 
 $args['rewrite']['slug']       = '.' into  $args['rewrite']['slug']       = '/'